# StackScrollView used inside main view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have seen StackScrollView made by Rafeeq now all I want is to add in my main view.
I have a "ALBUM " button and after cliking on it I want to open StackScrollView screen where I can show my album. Plz help me . Thanx in advace

Answer (score 0):

all what you have to do 
its to declare your StackScrollViewController  and then add it to your current view

```
StackScrollViewController stackview=[[StackScrollViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:stackview.view];
```

of course in your button click event

Comment: On click on button "ALBUM" root view comes but on cliking it nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

normaly it must work fine ...
maybe if you show us  your code it will help to resolve your problem 
anyway try this it must work

```
StackScrollViewController *sampleView = [[StackScrollViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:NO];
```